# How to tell if an ICollectionView is currently filterable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter, icollectionview

I am binding the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGrid` to a property in my ViewModel. I am then creating an `ICollectionView` and creating a default view with the `DataGrid`'s item source like so:

`_displayItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_displayItems);`

where `_displayItems` is a `List` and `_displayItemsView` is an `ICollectionView`.

Now the problem I am having is that I am allowing users to filter the data grid like so:

```
                        _displayItemsView.Filter = delegate(object item)
                        {
                            DISPLAY_ITEM displayItem = (DISPLAY_ITEM)item;
                            if ((displayItem.RETAIL_ITEM_DPCI.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(value.ToUpper()))
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
```

This works most of the time just great, but if the user is currently editing or adding a row in the `DataGrid` an un-handled exception is thrown by the `ICollectionView`. How should I go about detecting if either:

1. The `DataGrid` is currently being modified or
2. The `ICollectionView` is not in a state to be filtered?

Any guidance is appreciated, and I am open to ideas. Thanks!

Comment: The exception would have a message property on it.  What's in the message?

Comment: @GarryVass The message is "'Filter' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question number 1, the WPF DataGrid has transaction semantics available to you.  If the objects in your bound collection implement `IEditableObject`, your code will get three notifications: begin edit, end edit, and cancel edit.  You can track these notifications and implement a bit of housekeeping code to tell whether or not the DataGrid is being modified.  Depending upon your design, you will need to set the DataGrid's `SelectionUnit`/`SelectionMode`  properties to be consistent with the notifications you want.

For your question number 2, when the underlying collection inherits from IList (`ObservableCollection` for example), you can get a `ListCollectionView` by casting `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`.

The `ListCollectionView` has several properties on it that will give you the information you need...

- `CurrentEditItem` and `CurrentAddItem` will point to their respective
  objects when those states are active.
- `IsAddingNew` will tell you if an add transaction is in progress
- `IsEditingItem` will tell you if an edit transaction is in progress
- `IsInUse` will tell if there are any current subscribers

Using these properties and the IEditableObject interface will give you all the information needed to avert the exception you have been getting.